# Center page content

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

How can I center content page in the horizontal axis in Blazor?

So far I've been using MudBlazor's MudPaper for this but after upgrading to .NET8 this stopped working:

```
<MudPaper Class="d-flex justify-space-between flex-grow-1 gap-4" Elevation="0">
```

...so I'm looking a standard Blazor solution to this and I cannot find anything in Google that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for in this case is CSS.

Blazor is mainly a programing framework running on web assambly that mostly replaces javascript (javascript interop is still needed for some functions).

You can center a html object in the horizontal axis by creating a CSS class and then use it on the object:

```css
.my-class {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<MudPaper Class="my-class" Elevation="0"> Test </MudPaper>
```

Comment: Where should I put the CSS code?

Comment: Ok, I've put the CSS directly in the tag and it's working: `<MudPaper Style="display: flex; justify-content: center;" Elevation="0">`

Comment: You CAN do this, but you should learn not to.  You should practice building a css library for your site.